# Image Transform Quality settings

Tags: image-transforms

This is a simple question but I haven't been able to find the answer. Does the Image Transform Quality setting "Auto" mean that no compression will be applied to the transform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should probably be more accurately renamed to `Default` instead of `Auto`, but if that is selected, then it will use the [defaultImageQuality](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#defaultImageQuality) config setting value.